# Images Move around screen with finger in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, touch

I am developing a drawing application for iOS.

I have created a list of images and when user taps on any of the images that will be selected and I also get the tag value of the selected images.

After selection I want to move the images around the screen with finger and I have successfully completed this process, but when I want to apply the tag I will not get the tag value of images with touch.  My code for moving the images is below.  In this View array is my on screen selected image Array.

```
CGPoint firstTouch = [touch locationInView:selectedPerson_ImageView];
for (UIImageView *view in viewArray) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, firstTouch)) 
    {
        toMove = view;
    }
}
```

How do I get the tag value of images to be moved?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the tag value of touch location view by using this

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
       UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
       int viewTag=[touch view].tag;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how its recognize the imageview. I have perent view then One imageview subview and afterward one more Imageview which is subview of last image view  so how I will apply tag its always show 0 value.I think this is not which i want I am already work with viewwithtag method.

Comment: I think your imageViews have userInteractionEnabled=NO state. so that's why your not getting the imageView tags. Once check this one.